# forfiles loop to list files created after a certain time

Tags: batch-file

```
File1.txt 09/25/2016 2:00
File2.txt 09/25/2016 3:00
File3.txt 09/25/2016 3:01
```

I only want to list the files created after 2:00

What I have so far works for the date:

```
set year=%date:~10,4%
set month=%date:~4,2%
set day=%date:~7,2%
set fileDATE=%month%/%day%/%year%
forfiles /p %DIRName% /D +%fileDATE%  >> %workingDir%\list.txt
@ECHO off
FOR /f %%a IN (%workingDir%\list.txt) DO (
echo   %%a 
)
```

how do I separate by time difference in my loop?

Comment: your script is locale dependent. Here %date% returns 26/09/2016

Comment: I cannot answer since my locale won't fit yours, but I suggest that you loop through the files using `%%~ta` which will give you the date and time of the files.